# Select values between from and to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

```
SELECT Q.mem_id
FROM   tb_mem_share Q,
       tb_member Mb
WHERE  Mb.mem_id = Q.mem_id
       AND Q.share_num_from BETWEEN '42368' AND '42378'

SELECT *
FROM   tb_mem_share
WHERE  share_num_from >= 42368
       AND share_num_from <= 42378
```

Running this I get only the second record:

```
   mem_id   |  share_num_from  |  share_num_to  |  no_of_shares  |  share_amt
 -----------+------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------
  KA003871  |       42360      |     42369      |     10         |    10000
  KA000401  |       42370      |     42379      |     10         |    10000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have two queries there, trying to do what? Add sample table data, and the expected result (as formatted text).

Comment: Don't compare numbers to strings. `'42368'` is  a character value, **not**  a number. `42368` is a number

Answer (score 2):

share_num_from in your first record is 42360 and is not between '42368' and '42378'

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to select based on values from your from & to column you should at least include them in your select:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_mem_share
WHERE share_num_from >= 42368
  AND share_num_to <= 42378;
```

Currently you were filtering on from twice.